# Toggling the Caption on a continuous Form

Tags: ms-access, togglebutton

On a continuous form I am attempting to toggle the caption of a toggle button to match the button’s state.  In this case when the record/state is True, I would like the button to read “Current” and if the record is False have the button read “Obsolete”.

[image]

The script below works in switching between the two desired values but is switches all of the visible buttons and not for the individual records. I am not sure how to tie the individual records to the individual togglebutton's caption.

```
Private Sub Toggle5_Click()
    If Me.Toggle5.Value = True Then
        Me.Toggle5.Caption = "Current"
      Else:
        Me.Toggle5.Caption = "Obsolete"
    End If
End Sub
```

I am using MS- Access 2013, I expect this question has been answer before, I have not found a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gustav wrote, you cannot do this directly. All static properties of controls in a continuous form always apply to all instances of that control.

Possible workaround:

Use a **textbox** (disabled & locked, perhaps with special effect = Raised) to show the text, with a control source like this:

```
= IIf([Status]=True, "Current", "Obsolete")
```

Put a transparent button on top of it, for easy clickability (it won't show a  Click animation though).

Use [Conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-6ba9e9fa-4347-4183-b335-44e43b05e22f) to set the background color of the textbox.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It is not the answer I was looking for but it was expected.  I'll try your textbox suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

An unbound control in a continuous form carries the same values and properties on all records.